# In PyMC, the "thin" argument seems no more in use. What can be put instead?

Tags: python, pymc

Trying to understand PyMC through examples, I made a small model referring to a set of birds weight (data observed: `y20`), supposedly coming from a normal population `N(mu, sigma)`.

```
import pymc as pm
import arviz as az

with pm.Model() as model:
    
    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    mu = pm.Uniform('mu', lower = 0, upper = 2000)
    sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma', lower = 0, upper = 100)

    # Likelihood of observations
    lkd = pm.Normal('likelihood', mu = mu, sigma = sigma, observed = y20)
    
    # Expected value of outcome
    weights = pm.Normal('weights', mu = mu, sigma = sigma)
```

This `pm.Model()` runs without problem. Now about sampling...

Browsing docs, I found in the **"read the docs" tutorial**, here: [HERE](https://pymcmc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html), `paragraph 3.5.1`, the following sentence: *MCMC often results in strong autocorrelation among samples that can result in imprecise posterior inference. To circumvent this, it is useful to thin the sample by only retaining every k th sample, where k is an integer value. This thinning interval is passed to the sampler via the thin argument.*

So, after my model, I used this new line:

```
with model:
    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune = 1000, thin = 10)
```

and I got a strange consequence:

```
ValueError: Unused step method arguments: {'thin'}
```

Has something changed in PyMC?

Comment: sounds like a question that you should also post over on https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues, after searching to make sure no one's already filed that. If their docs contain code that tell you to use `thin`, and the library throws an error, that's a bug and you should notify the authors so they can fix both the code, and if necessary, the docs. And that's definitely something you should have done before putting up a bounty post, there is a clear best person to ask, and by posting here, you're not asking _them_ =)

Answer (score 0):

The doc link that you shared seems to be outdated. The home page for the reference link that you shared:https://pymcmc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
shows that it is for version 2x (check 1.3 under introduction: What's new in version 2) and the current version is 5.1.1

As you can see on their tutorial that you shared, they are using iter too as a parameter. However, you are using tune. You are merging input definitions from two different versions.

Thier git page points to this doc page as reference and seems to be updated too:
https://www.pymc.io/welcome.html

You can refer to line 317 in this file to see the parameters accepted by the sample function and see if any of them fits your requirement:
https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/main/pymc/sampling/mcmc.py